# Re-uploaded my website but it's still loading old css files

Tags: ubuntu, cache, apache2, css

I have VPS running Ubuntu 16.0.4 with Apache. I have a website uploaded there and I wanted to make a few changes to my css. Re-uploaded my CSS file but the website still uses the old one.

Here is what I tried with no luck:

- Restarting Apache
- Clearing my browser cache
- Reuploading my whole site
- Trying a different IPS
- Trying a different browser which I have never visited my site with

Here is what worked:

- Renaming the CSS file
- Changing the domain

Obviously, none of the above are permanent solutions.

I do have HTTP Headers set for Cache-Control but those only affect the browser-cache right? f

Could it be that the VPS provider is doing some caching?

I am really lost right now..

Any feedback is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a proxy cache between your browser and the web server ?

Comment: You might want to use [cache busting query strings](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/), something like `?v=1` (after your next upload `?v=2` etc. ...) appended to the filename if referencing, for example inside your `HTML`.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that it's working when changing the css file name would indicate to me that some sort of caching is going on.

Can you test the stylesheet using a version system? - here's a good write-up on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/)

Comment: Broken link updated.